# NHibernate Search and Lucene initial indexing of IList

Tags: nhibernate, search, lucene.net

I have some boring problem of indexing IList using Lucene, and I can not fix.

My entity contains IList which I apply IndexedEmbedded attribute like this:

```
[ScriptIgnore] //will not serialize
[IndexedEmbedded(Depth = 1, Prefix = "BookAdditionalInfos_"]
public virtual IList<BookAdditionalInfo> BookAdditionalInfos { get; set; }
```

Also, some other properties used Field attribute for indexing:

```
[Field(Index.Tokenized, Store = Store.Yes)]
```

After marking entity for indexing, I have to make initial indexing of 12 millions of rows (using batch processing). And everything works perfect until I start to index IList called BookAdditionalInfos. Without this IndexedEmbedded attribute (or without indexing this IList) everything is OK, and every property mark with Field attribute will be indexed.

I am using Fluent NHibernate.

What can be a problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**: Also I looked at http://ayende.com/blog/3992/nhibernate-search, but without any results

The problem is: when I try to index IList, indexing taking forever and nothing will be indexed. Without indexing this IList (or without specify IndexedEmbedded to IList) indexing is OK, and I got indexed results.

**EDIT (Initial Indexing function):**

```
public void BuildInitialBookSearchIndex()
        {
            FSDirectory directory = null;
            IndexWriter writer = null;

            var type = typeof(Book);

            var info = new DirectoryInfo(GetIndexDirectory());

            //if (info.Exists)
            //{
            //    info.Delete(true);
            //}

            try
            {
                directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(Path.Combine(info.FullName, type.Name), true);
                writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (directory != null)
                {
                    directory.Close();
                }

                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }

            var fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(Session);

            var currentIndex = 0;
            const int batchSize = 5000;

            while (true)
            {
                var entities = Session
                    .CreateCriteria<Book>()
                    .SetFirstResult(currentIndex)
                    .SetMaxResults(batchSize)
                    .List();

                using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var entity in entities)
                    {
                        fullTextSession.Index(entity);
                    }

                    currentIndex += batchSize;

                    Session.Flush();
                    tx.Commit();
                    Session.Clear();
                }

                if (entities.Count < batchSize)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem? is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: doesn't throw an exception. Initial indexing function which I use for indexing 12 millions of rows is provided with question above. I guess that there is some problem with this function, when IList is mark as IndexedEmbedded

Comment: I'm confused, when you say a problem what do you mean, no exception is being thrown, OK. Is it taking forever? is it indexing the field incorrectly?

Comment: Prescott, thank you for reply. The problem is: when I try to index IList, indexing taking forever and nothing will be indexed. Without indexing this IList (or without specify IndexedEmbedded to IList) indexing is OK, and I got indexed results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've got a classic N+1 select problem there - basically when you're selecting your books, you're not also selecting the BookAdditionalInfos, so NHibernate will have to issue a new select for each and every book to retrieve the BookAdditionalInfo's for that book while indexing.
A quick fix would be to change your select to:

```
   var entities = Session
                .CreateCriteria<Book>()
                .SetFetchMode("BookAdditionalInfos", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                .SetFirstResult(currentIndex)
                .SetMaxResults(batchSize)
                .List();
```

You'll probably run into additional problems with your paging now however because it will do a join onto the BookAdditionalInfo table giving you multiple rows for the same entity in your result set, so you might want to look at doing something like:

```
   var pagedEntities = DetachedCriteria.For<Book>()
                .SetFirstResult(currentIndex)
                .SetMaxResults(batchSize)
                .SetProjection(Projections.Id());

   var entities = Session
                .CreateCriteria<Book>()
                .Add(Property.ForName("id").In(pagedEntities))
                .SetFetchMode("BookAdditionalInfos", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                .List();
```

Comment: Martin, thank you for your answer. I try this solution, but without any results. I try to fetched BookAdditionalInfos too, but it didn't index. Neither books are indexed when generic list is mark as IndexedEmbedded. I made workaround, I indexed BookAdditionalInfo class where I keep reference to Book and mark Book entity as IndexedEmbedded, and everything is OK. Thank you for your second suggestion.